# USB webcam not acknowledged as AVMediaTypeVideo - XCode/Mac

Tags: webcam, avcapturedevice

I am using XCode version 9.4 and writing an application to run on a Mac.
I have a Logitech C525 USB webcam and am trying to capture video from it and place into a view.  I am having a problem early-on trying to get a handle to my device.

When the following code is executed, "devices" comes back as null:

```
NSArray *devices = nil;
devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType : AVMediaTypeVideo ];
```

However, when the following code is executed, the the loop iterates one time, with "device" appearing to be a reference to my USB camera, but the "if" statement does not acknowledge it as a type with AVMediaTypeVideo:

```
AVCaptureDevice *device;
for( device in [AVCaptureDevice devices]){
    if( [device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]){
        NSString  *modelID = [device modelID ];
        NSLog(@"Model %@", modelID );
    }
}
```

So, it appears that the camera is acknowledged as an AVCaptureDevice, but it is not of type AVMediaTypeVideo.  Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

Under the project settings "Capabilities", for the App Sandbox, "Camera" and "USB" must be checked and the sandbox set to "On".  Now the USB webcam is enumerated.